# Initialise C Struct in Order to Be Used Globally

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

I have the following struct:

#### dict.c

```
typedef struct dictionary {
    int key;
    char *word;
    char *desc;
} dict;
```

#### main.c

```
#include "dict.c"

dict * d;

some function() {
    d->key = 1;
}
```

This throws an error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type.

How would I allow the struct to be read in by other functions?

Comment: You need to allocate memory for `d`

Comment: Because `d` doesn't pointing to a structure. An empty glass!

Comment: In general, type declarations belong in header files `.h`, not code files `.c`. Also, consider using the same name for typedef and tag.

Comment: @Arun
If I malloc it, I get this:

invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘dict’
 d = (dict *)malloc(sizeof(dict));
                           ^

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @user3295336: Please refer to my answer for details.

Comment: type `dict *d = (dict *)malloc(sizeof(dict));` , `d = (dict *)malloc(sizeof(dict));` //set to globall variable at in function

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `dictionary` object on the heap, then you need to allocate memory for that, such as the following.

```
dict * pd = NULL;
/* ... */
pd = malloc( sizeof *pd );
if( !pd ) { /* handle malloc failure, e.g. syslog, assert */ }
pd->key = 1;
```

Otherwise you may have the `dictionary` object in the stack.

```
dict d;
d.key = 1;
```

Also, conventionally, type definitions are kept in header `.h` files.

```
// dictionary.h
typedef struct DictElem {
    int key;
    char *word;
    char *desc;
} DictElem;

// main.c
#include "dictionary.h"

// Then, either
DictElem * pd = NULL;
// ... or
DictElem d;
// ... and see above
```

Comment: Or either `dict d1;`  then `dict* d = &d1;`

Comment: This compiles okay, however, I am still getting the original error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type.

For example, when I declare: `dict * d = NULL;`
I attempt to use it in a function (in main.c) e.g. `void function() { dict->key = 1; }`

Comment: Hope `#include "dictionary.h"` is not missed.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating a global pointer, don't. Alloc the real struct and initialize on declaration:

```
#include "dict.c"

dict d = {.key = 1, .word = &word_data, .desc = &desc_data};
```

Comment: Just should mention that you are using C99 notation.

Comment: I attempt this and I get error: variable ‘d’ has initializer but incomplete type
 dict d = { .key = 0, .word = "word", .desc = "desc" };